# How to measure non-3D GPU performance on Windows

Tags: windows, graphics-card, performance, gpu

I am currently running Windows 10 1607 on two different machines with two different sets of graphics hardware. On Machine A, dragging windows is choppy, scrolling is slow, right-clicking to display a context menu is so slow you can see each line of text draw. On Machine B, none of these issues exist. If I run a GPU benchmark on Machine A, Furmark produces a high score. On Machine B, the same version of Furmark produces a lower score than Machine A.

I need a better way to measure the difference of desktop graphics between the machines than "it looks bad when you drag the window."

**How can I record quantitative performance data for non-3D desktop graphics in Windows?**

Comment: post more details. Which GPUs do both devices use? Also post all HW specs

Comment: I've seen issues like this on machines with powerful GPU's. I wouldn't bother trying to benchmark non-3d graphics - and instead focus on whether the GPU driver is having issues on W10 1607 or if anything else is involved in the display stack (think VNC mirror driver etc...)

Comment: 3dmark.com look at user submitted scores.  Also gpuboss.com can compare video cards.  The higher 3d is the higher 2d will be.  I think pcmark has some 2d benchmarks with user submitted results for comparing.